# How to find the matrix of a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$ to $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, representation-theory

Let $T:\Bbb R^{2\times2}\rightarrow P_2$ be a linear transformation, where $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$ is the vector space of all $2\times2$ matrices and $P_2$ is the vector space of all polynomials up to second order.

We consider the basis $B$ for $R^{2×2}$,

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}, $$

and the basis $C$ for the vector space $P_2$,

$$\ C = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & t & t^{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The transformation $T$ is defined by

$$T\begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\ c &d\end{pmatrix} = (c + d) + (b −c)t + (2a + b)t^{2}.$$

**How do you find the matrix representation of $T$ relative to the chosen bases $B$ and $C$?**

I think the first step would be to take the transformation $T$ of each basis vector $B_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B_4 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. If that's correct, **what's the intuitive idea behind this?  Why would I want to see how the basis vectors transform?**

Comment: as a brief note,  $P_2$ in this context would be polynomials of degree 2 or less.  Polynomials of exactly degree 2 don't even form a vector space as they aren't closed under addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out how basis vectors transform under $T$:
$$
\begin{split} 
T\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} &= 2t^2 \\
T\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} &= t + t^2 \\
T\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} &= 1-t \\
T\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} &= 1.
\end{split}
$$

Then, the columns of the matrix of the transformation, are the transformed basis vectors, i.e.

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 &-1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

To find a matrix for a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$, you just need to apply T to the basis of V. i.e.  Assume $\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_n\}$ is the basis of $V$, then the matrix of T consists of $T(e_1), T(e_2), ..., T(e_n)$ as its columns (with the same order of the basis).

In your case, $ e_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
e_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},e_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, e_4=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$ Now if you calculate $T(e_i)$ you get a 3 by 4 matrix. For example $T(e_1)=2t^2= (0,0,2)$ so the first column of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0 \\
 2
\end{pmatrix}.$